# Show full URL in the squid access.log log

Tags: ubuntu-18.04, squid

Im running an Squid-Proxy and want to see the full requested URL in the /var/log/squid/access.log log.
The only thing that is shown is:

```
1607565964.095     64 XXX.XXX.126.82 TCP_TUNNEL/200 13744 CONNECT www.mediamarkt.de:443 XXX HIER_DIRECT/XXX.XXX.208.234 -
```

I requested an full link from mediamarkt, not only the main homepage.
So is there an way to see the full requested link?

For requests against my server it works:

```
1607565951.279      0 XXX.XXX.122.16 NONE/400 3947 GET /boaform/admin/formLogin?username=XXXXX&psd=XXXXX - HIER_NONE/- text/html
```

Comment: That's a TLS/HTTPS session - are you using `ssl_bump` if not the you won't be able to see inside. This is off-topc here and would be better posted on [su] or [sf] as this place is for programming questions, not config/how-to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For showing the full requested URL, i need to use ssl_bump.